# mouse instant speed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I want to know the **instant speed** of the mouse in my `update()` function.

But here's my problem: when `fps` is high (>30), `update()` is sometimes triggered twice between two `onmousemove` events. And so, even if the mouse *is* moving, it's considered still for a moment.

I think this is about the relation between `setInterval()` and the `onmousemove` event. So here is the code that matters :

```
var fps = 60;
setInterval(update,1000/fps);

function update() {
    console.log('update');
}

document.onmousemove = function(){
    console.log('mouse');
}
```

It displays `"update"` 60 times a second, and `"mouse"` each time the `onmousemove` event triggers.

When the mouse is still, it goes : `"update"` `"update"` `"update"` `"update"` ...
When the mouse moves, it is : `"update"` `"mouse"` `"update"` `"mouse"`...

But sometimes : `"update"` `"mouse"` **`"update"` `"update"`** `"mouse"`...
And that's bullshit because the mouse *IS* moving.

So I tried different mouse movements, to see if there was a pattern, but no: circles, loops, straight lines... I also tried another mouse, but it's not a hardware problem.

I've found a partial solution. With a `counter++` at each `update()`, and `counter=0` when `onmousemove`, it allows me to skip the second `update()` of a sequence of updates. But it's not perfect because sometimes there are 3 or 4 `update()` in a row.

.

Is it solvable ? How to be *SURE* there is one and only one `update()` between 2 `onmousemove` ?

---

PS 1: The more `fps`, the more `update()` called between two events.
PS 2: It's fine if `onmousemove` is triggered several times between two `update()`.
PS 3: I tried with `document.addEventListener('mousemove')`, it's the same.
PS 4: I'm on a mac

Answer (score 1):

This is unusual..

Mouse events should fire much more often than once every 30ms.

Two test snippets.

The first snippet records mouse moves and frame updates and will show a stream of events, plus the max mouse events per 160 events, and max mouse events in a row.

On my machine I am getting max 9 mouse events in a row and max 142/18 mouse events / frame events,  running at 60FPS

But that said you can lose mouse events. The second snippet deliberately blocks all events for 26ms (approx 30FPS) and when I run that the max mouse events between frames is 4 and max rate is 115/45 mouse events to frame events. I am losing around 27 mouse events every 2.66 seconds

But still this does not explain your mouse problem.

most likely reason for your slow mouse is that another event listener is consuming mouse events. Use the dev tools to check for other mouse event listeners that may be chewing up events.

Apart from that all I can say is look at the OS mouse settings as could be the source of the problem.

Additional note, when testing the code on this page the max mouse events between frames is 3 (second snippet) as opposed to 4 on my testing environment. Reason Unknown????

**Mouse events V frame events**

```js
var lastTime = 0;
var max = 0;
var maxInARow = 0;
var inARow = 0;
var record = [];
function recordEvent(type){
  record.push(type);
  if(record.length > 160){
    record.shift();
  }
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
  recordEvent(".");
  inARow += 1;
});
function update(time){
  recordEvent("|");  
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < record.length;i ++){
      if(record[i] === "."){
        count += 1;
      }    
  }
  maxInARow = Math.max(inARow,maxInARow);
  mousebet.textContent = maxInARow;
  inARow = 0;

  mouserate.textContent = "Max : "+ max +"/"+(record.length - max)+ " Current : " + count +"/"+(record.length - count) ;
  framerate.textContent = (1000 / (time-lastTime)).toFixed(0);
  lastTime = time;
  stream.textContent = record.join("");
  if(max < count && record.length === 160){
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.textContent = stream.textContent;
      document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  max = Math.max(max,count);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
body {
  font-family :Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
div {
  width : 100%;
}
```

```html
FPS : <div id="framerate"></div>
Mouse : <div id="mouserate"></div>
Max mouse events between frames : <div id="mousebet"></div>
Events : <div id="stream"></div>
```

**Mouse events V Blocking frame events**

```js
    var lastTime = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var maxInARow = 0;
    var inARow = 0;
    var record = [];
    function recordEvent(type){

        
      record.push(type);
      if(record.length > 160){
        record.shift();
      }
    }
    function mouseE(){
      recordEvent(".");
      inARow += 1;
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseE);

    function update(time){  
      if(performance){
        var n = performance.now();
      }else{
        document.body.innerHTML = "FAILED no performance API."
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove",mouseE);
        return;
      }      
      
      recordEvent("|");  
      var count = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < record.length;i ++){
          if(record[i] === "."){
            count += 1;
          }    
      }
      maxInARow = Math.max(inARow,maxInARow);
      mousebet.textContent = maxInARow;
      inARow = 0;
      max = Math.max(max,count);
      mouserate.textContent = "Max : "+ max +"/"+(record.length - max)+ " Current : " + count +"/"+(record.length - count) ;
      framerate.textContent = (1000 / (time-lastTime)).toFixed(0);
      lastTime = time;
      stream.textContent = record.join("");
      // block javascript context till 28 ms used up;
      while(performance.now() - n < 26);

      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
    body {
      font-family :Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    div {
      width : 100%;
    }
```

```html
    26ms Blocking frame Event test <br>
    FPS : <div id="framerate"></div>
    Mouse : <div id="mouserate"></div>
    Max mouse events between frames : <div id="mousebet"></div>
    Events : <div id="stream"></div>
```

Comment: Your numbers are impressive ! I get 2max at 60fps, 6 at 30fps. With no other mouseEvent. So I gess it comes from the OS. I may turn to this strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22048799/2351921